# how to exceed maximum iis post request Limit?

Tags: asp.net, http, iis, limit

i have an asp web application, and a service witch people use to send large chunks of date trough HTTP POST.
bu Data riches many megabytes rejects the request and return nothing.

i tried to use this but didn't work. to change the limit to 10 megabytes.

```
<system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="10000000" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your web.config, too

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1000000" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Check this link for more info: http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/requestlimits

Comment: i used this config and witch wrote in my question together and worked well.